# Match a single character in a DataView RowFilter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, dataview, rowfilter

I'm wondering if there is any possible way of applying a `RowFilter` on a `DataView` which provides single character matching?

**e.g. DataView.RowFilter = "SOME_COL like 'A_BCD%';**

where the underscore represents a single-character match in Oracle SQL, and `%` is a wildcard of 0 or more characters.

Apparently RowFilter only supports wildcards (`* or %)` at the beginning or end of the matching expression. The only other idea I've had is to iterate through the rows and delete ones that don't match a regular expression, but this is not ideal.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Linq to Datasets to do this

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("test");
        dt.Columns.Add("SOME_COL", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add("AABCDEFG");
        dt.Rows.Add("AZBCDEFG");
        dt.Rows.Add("AZZBCDEFG");
        dt.Rows.Add("ABC");

        Regex r = new Regex("A\\wBCDE");

        DataView dv 
           = (from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
              where r.IsMatch(t.Field<string>("SOME_COL"))
             select t).AsDataView();

        foreach(DataRowView row in dv)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row[0]);
        }


    }


}
```

outputs

```
AABCDEFG
AZBCDEFG
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively,

```
DataView.RowFilter = "Substring(SOME_COL, 1, 1) = 'A' and Substring(SOME_COL, 3, 3) = 'BCD';"
```

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know you could write a string expression to evaluate for a row filter. Is there a reason for the un-matched parenthesis at the end?

Comment: @russdot Typo from copy and paste testing. Fixed.